# How can I get an object value from inside an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

What im trying to do is to get an object value that is inside of an array.
The model is like this:

```
_id:630e2a2250283de03b2dc920
fullName: John
phone:"+1234..."
createdAt:2022-08-30T15:17:54.608+00:00
selectedClients:Array
   0:Object
     phone:"+4567..."
     fullName:"Client1"
     _id:630e2a8f8367a2aaac3343b4
     createdAt:2022-08-30T15:19:43.372+00:00
   1:Object
     phone:"+7890..."
     fullName:"Client2"
     _id:630e2b73d42ddc8d622e860f
     createdAt:2022-08-30T15:23:31.883+00:00
__v:0
```

So what I want to find is the Client1.
I get the user id and the client id.
I have tried a way, but it returns me the whole user model, and not the Client1 object only.

```
exports.removeTrustee = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user_id = req.params.user_id.split("-")[1];
  const client_id = ObjectId(req.params.client_id.split("-")[1]);

  const client = await User.find({
     selectedClients: { $elemMatch: { _id: client_id } },
  });
```

So basically what I want is to return only the client_id object that I put as a parameter.

Example:

```
phone:"+4567..."
fullName:"Client1"
_id:630e2a8f8367a2aaac3343b4
createdAt:2022-08-30T15:19:43.372+00:00
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $elemMatch projection operator to limit an array field like s to a single matched element, but you can't remove the s level of your document using find:

```
const client = await User.find({}, {_id: 0, s: {$elemMatch: {_id: client_id}}});
```